# Need help htaccess movies.php to /movies/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to make movies.php to /movies/ with htaccess?

Example:

```
http://domain.com/movies.php?movie=avengers
```

to

```
 http://domain.com/movies/avengers
```